# Creating sqlite database using dump file programmatically

Tags: c#, sqlite, dump

I've created a dump file from a Sqlite database and I want to create another sqlite database based on this file in my `C#` application.

*a sample of the dump file:*

```
drop table if exists [main].[tblAyah];

CREATE TABLE [main].[tblAyah] (
  [IdAyah] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ON CONFLICT REPLACE AUTOINCREMENT, 
  [AyahNumber] INTEGER, 
  [Page] INTEGER);

insert into [main].[tblAyah] values(1, 1, 1, 'somthing','somthing');
...
```

So My question is:

Is there a particular way to do that or I just have to read the file as string and run each command line one by one like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> tblCommand;
//Reading the dump file line by one and adding to tblCommand
using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(
"DataSource=\"|DataDirectory|\\newDb.db\";Persist Security Info=False;"))
{
    con.Open();
    foreach (string command in tblCommand)
    using (SqlCeCommand com =
    new SqlCeCommand(command, con))
    {
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by creating a new connection, reading the SQL dump into memory, then using `SQLiteCommand` `ExecuteNonQuery` to apply the dump to the current connection.

Note: I would recommend using `SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder` to create your connection string, and `SQLiteConnection` for connecting. It's not clear in the question why you are using `SqlCeConnection`.

Before you start, install `System.Data.SQLite` from NuGet.

```
using System.Data.SQLite;

// ...

var builder = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        DataSource = @"C:\<Path to your data directory>\<New database file name>.db",
        Version = 3,
        // Any other connection configuration goes here
    };

string connectionString = builder.ToString();

using(SQLiteConnection databaseConnection = new SQLConnection(connectionString)) {
    // Open the connection to the new database
    databaseConnection.Open();

    // Import the SQL file database dump into the in-memory database
    SQLiteCommand command = databaseConnection.CreateCommand();
    string dumpFile = Path.Combine("Path to your sql dump file", "YourDumpFileName.sql");
    string importedSql = File.ReadAllText(dumpFile);
    command.CommandText = importedSql;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to execute multiple commands with one execute. They have to be separated with a ";". Try it. And if you get errors, tell us of them. But it should work and it is a good solution to Create tables or to update your database structure, because if one Statement is wrong, none of them is executed.